# Building a reusable carousel paragraph item

Tags: views

I'm using the [Paragraphs](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs) Module to create Paragraphs Items for easy page/content creation. I'm trying to create a paragraph item which displays a carousel (slideshow).

**The idea:**
The user wants to display images in a carousel, selects the slider paragraph, uploads his images (or reuse uploaded images with the Media module). Done.

**The solution** (which doesn't work):
Needed modules: paragraphs, views, views_bootstrap, viewfield

- Create a paragraph with two fields: one image field and a viewfield
- Creating a block view, which displays the image of the paragraph

The problem is that it shows all uploaded images. If node 1 has 2 images and node 2 has 3 images, both nodes display 5 images. I added a contextual filter to the view (Paragraphs item: Paragraphs item ID) and provided a default filter value: "Content ID from URL". But it still doesn't work – a couple of nodes show up correctly, other ones doesn't.

It seems to me that the contextual filter uses the node id as paragraph id, but node id != paragraph id.
Can somebody reproduce this behaviour and have an idea how to solve this? I think I need a contextual filter for the node, but can't define it.